# Who should I call to look at clothes washer that fills with water after it has drained?

Tags: clothes-washer

Who do you call to fix this problem, a plumber or the Whirlpool guy? Water backs into the forum after it has trained.  it takes a while after the drum is empty.

Comment: What type of outlet connection is the washer using? If the washer's hose makes too good a seal with the pipe it drains into, water can sometimes be siphoned back into the machine. There should either be enough of an opening to let air in to break the vacuum,  or a check valve to prevent backflow, or both.

Comment: Is it clean water or drained water that you find?

Answer (score 1):

Call an appliance repairman.  Likely a check valve on the drain line has failed.